# how to convert dictionary where values are stored in a list to df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary that I want to convert into DataFrame, the problem I'm having is my dictionary is in the following format:

```
sample_dict = {'test':['test string',['feature1','feature2', 'feature3']]}
```

When trying to convert using something like

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([sample_dict])
```

I get:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is something like:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `orient`

```
out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sample_dict, orient='index')
Out[287]: 
                0                               1
test  test string  [feature1, feature2, feature3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use [`from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) as well.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d).T
```

---

```
                0                               1
test  test string  [feature1, feature2, feature3]
```